# How do I read into a string list contents of a MySql view in java?

Tags: java, mysql, workbench

I can not read contents from a MySql View inside my table.

Whenever I make a query to read from a table everything works alright. If I try doing the same for a view, the 'table' is not found.

```
public List<String> selectTable(String tableName) throws Exception
{
    List<String> rezultat = new ArrayList<String>();

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    ResultSetMetaData resMD = null;

    try
    {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        res = stmt.executeQuery("Select * FROM " + tableName);
        resMD = res.getMetaData();

        while(res.next())
        {
            String aux = "";

            for(int i = 1; i <= resMD.getColumnCount(); i++)
            {
                String auxMic = res.getString(i);

                aux += " | " + auxMic;

            }
            aux += " | ";
            rezultat.add(aux);
        }
        return rezultat;
    }
    finally
    {
        close(stmt, res);
    }
}
```

Trying to run the following piece of code instead of the one that's shown gives me an error stating that 'the table is not found'.

`res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM agentieimobiliara2.detalii_dupa_pret;");`

Where 'agentieimobiliara' is my database and 'detalii_dupa_pret' is the name of the created view.

Comment: you  have  agentieimobiliara2   not  agentieimobiliara

Comment: You are actually right. That fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-view) for guidance in creating & calling a MySQL view.